# Bootstrap 3 with sidebar footnotes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page that has a left-side nav sidebar, a center column of text, and a right-side column for footnotes. Is there any way to lay out the footnotes so that they're next to the appropriate paragraph?

As you can see from the image, they're spread throughout the page.

[image: three column layout with footnotes scattered around third column]

As far as my knowledge extends, padding or positioning won't work, as each footnote needs to be next to its specific paragraphs (but I'm open to suggestions). I'd like it to be responsive enough for different monitor sizes, but it doesn't need to get down to mobile size.

I'm hoping there's a very simple answer that I just haven't been able to track down. Any help is appreciated - even "nope, there's no easy way to do it" so I don't waste any more time searching for a solution.

Here's my basic code (obviously greatly simplified):

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row full-page">
            <div class="left-sidebar col-sm-3">
                <!-- sidebar -->
            </div>
            <div class="main-content col-sm-9">
                <!-- text for main content -->
            </div>
            <div class="footnote col-sm-3">
                <!-- many footnotes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I also tried a bit of a hacky solution by just alternating paragraph/footnote/paragraph/footnote, but some paragraphs have multiple footnotes, so that approach didn't work either.

I have no applicable css at this time, but am open to any suggestions.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Have you tried to code a few css?

Comment: I've tried a few variations on padding and positioning, but like I said, I'm not having much luck with it. At this time, none of my CSS is applicable to this particular problem, so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "nope, there's no easy way to do it (with CSS alone)".  The problem is that you're trying to align one element (the citation) with a position on the screen that depends on layout (the reference), and please don't let any of the citations overlap.

That said, the longer answer is "sure, just use jquery".  Find each of your citation references, determine its top offset, and apply that offset to the matching citation.  (And please don't let any of the citations overlap.)

This jsfiddle should get you part-way there.
https://jsfiddle.net/7qfwjh2x/4/

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row full-page">
      <div class="left-sidebar col-sm-1">
        <!-- sidebar -->
      </div>
      <div class="main-content col-sm-6">
        <!-- text for main content -->
        <p>
            Some text<span data-footnote="1"></span>.
        </p>
        <p>
            Some more text<span data-footnote="2"></span>.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="footnote col-sm-4">
        <!-- many footnotes here -->
        <p data-footnote="1">FOOTNOTE 1</p>
        <p data-footnote="2">FOOTNOTE 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Process the html with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentCitationPosition = 0;

  // For each citation reference in the text.
  $('div.main-content span[data-footnote]').each(function(index) {
    // Add the citation number.
    var citationNum = $(this).data('footnote');
    $(this).html('(' + citationNum + ')');

    // Find the position of the citation reference, but don't overdraw an existing citation.
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    if (offset.top > currentCitationPosition) {
      currentCitationPosition = offset.top;
    }

    // Find the citation matching the citation reference.
    var citation = $('div.footnote p[data-footnote="' + citationNum + '"]');
    if (citation) {
      // Set this position to the offset.top of the reference, or below the previous citation.
      $(citation).offset({
        top: currentCitationPosition
      });
      // Pad by the height of the current citation to prevent overdraw.
      currentCitationPosition += $(citation).height();
    }

  });
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is perfect, exactly for what I'm looking for (& it's very reassuring to know that there's not some easy answer in Bootstrap that I just don't know about). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've made this, that maybe help you: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20321/

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.paragraph, .footnote {
    display: table-cell;
}
.footnote {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: none;
}

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row full-page">
            <!-- repeat foreach paragraph and apply css to paddin/margin = 0 -->
            <div class="row table-row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 left-sidebar paragraph">
                    <!-- sidebar -->
                    text
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 main-content paragraph">
                <!-- text for main content -->
                    <p>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 footnote">
                    <p>
                        footnote<br/>
                        footnote<br/>
                        footnote<br/>
                    </p>
                    <!-- many footnotes here -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row table-row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 left-sidebar paragraph">
                    <!-- sidebar -->
                    text
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 main-content paragraph">
                <!-- text for main content -->
                    <p>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                        texttexttexttext<br/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 footnote">
                    <p>
                        footnote<br/>
                        footnote<br/>
                        footnote<br/>
                    </p>
                    <!-- many footnotes here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```